# Laravel Multi level relationship in API Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

My problem is, the api resource loading which i really not needed. 
Look into my Api Resource files

//BoxItemResource.php

```
 public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'box_id'=> $this->box_id,
        'item_id'=> $this->item_id,
        'item'=> new ItemResource($this->item)
    ];
}
```

//ItemResource.php

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'shipping_price' => $this->shipping_price,
        'condition_id' => $this->condition_id,
        'condition' => new ConditionResource($this->condition)
    ];
}
```

//ConditionResource.php

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'=> $this->id,
        'name'=> $this->name
    ];
}
```

//controller

```
return BoxItemResource::collection(
        BoxItem::with([
            'item'
        ])->paginate(1)
    );
```

My problem is, I just need only BoxItem and Item here. I don't really want to load condition.
If i remove the condition relation from ItemResource.php, it will work. but the problem is I am using the ItemResource.php in some other place  which need this condition.

Is it possible to deny loading condition relation ship here.

more clearly, I want to load the relationship which I mention in controller(in ->with()) .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API resources allow for [conditional attribtues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes) and [conditional relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships).

For attributes, which in my opinion is sufficient to use in your case, this means you can simply wrap the attribute value in `$this->when($condition, $value)` and the whole attribute will be removed from the result if `$condition == false`. So a concrete example of your code:

```
return [
    'box_id'=> $this->box_id,
    'item_id'=> $this->item_id,
    'item'=> $this->when($this->relationLoaded('item'), new ItemResource($this->item))
];
```

Or if you prefer using the relationship style:

```
return [
    'box_id'=> $this->box_id,
    'item_id'=> $this->item_id,
    'item'=> new ItemResource($this->whenLoaded('item'))
];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Namoshek.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for [Conditional Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships)?

Ideally, it should look like the following:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'box_id'=> $this->box_id,
        'item' => ItemResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('item'))
    ];
}
```

The `item` key will only be present if the relationship has been loaded.