# How in Laravel 7 resources show only some fields of a creator?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, resources, laravel-7

In my Laravel 7.6 app I use resource collection with creator retrieved
and I want in some cases show not all creator fields, but only some of them. I have in my control:

```
$activeVotes = Vote
    ::getByStatus('A')
    ->where('votes.id', 1) 
    ->with('voteCategory')
    ->with('creator')
return (new VoteCollection($activeVotes));
```

In app/Http/Resources/VoteCollection.php I have :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class VoteCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public static $wrap = 'votes';

    public function toArray($request)
    {

        $this->collection->transform(function ($votes) {
            return new VoteResource($votes);
        });

        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

and in app/Http/Resources/VoteResource.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class VoteResource extends JsonResource
{

    public static $wrap = 'votes';
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'creator' => $this->whenLoaded('creator'),
            ...
```

How to defined if I need to show only some fields of creator above ?

**EDITED:**

```
My app/User.php has :

<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use DB;
...
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Billable;
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    use funcsTrait;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $userAvatarPropsArray = [];
    protected $avatar_filename_max_length = 255;
    protected $full_photo_filename_max_length = 255;
    protected static $password_length = 8;

    protected $fillable = [ 'username', 'email', 'status', 'provider_name', 'template_id', 'provider_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'website', 'password',
    'activated_at', 'avatar', 'full_photo', 'updated_at', 'verified' ];

    protected $hidden = [ 'password', 'remember_token'  ];
    ...

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote', 'creator_id', 'id');
    }
    ...
```

and app/Vote.php :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use App\MyAppModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class Vote extends MyAppModel
{
    use funcsTrait;
    use Sluggable;
    use HasTags;

    protected $table = 'votes';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'meta_keywords' => 'array'
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug', 'description', 'creator_id', 'vote_category_id', 'is_quiz', 'status', 'image'];
    protected static $logAttributes = ['*'];
    ...
    public function creator(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'creator_id','id');
    }
```

In Vote and user models there are referenced to other model.
Otherwize

```
   ->with('creator')
```

does not work.
Are there some options I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54435800/9193055) solution might do what you want, you could create a new resource for the creator and then call it inside your `VoteResource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options.

1. Use `hidden` on your `user` model

By using [`hidden`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json), see the Laravel docs, you specify which fields are shown in the JSON or Arrray representation of your model.

2. Select the fields in your `with` statement

```php
$activeVotes = Vote::getByStatus('A')->where('votes.id', 1) 
                                     ->with('voteCategory')
                                     ->with(['creator' => function ($query) {
                                         $query->select('id', 'first_name');
                                     }]);

return (new VoteCollection($activeVotes));
```

Your need to include the field `id`, as this is responsible to join these two.

Comment: I try :         $activeVotes = Vote
            ::getByStatus('A')
            ->with('voteCategory')
            ->with(['creator' => function ($query) {
                $query->select('first_name', 'last_name', 'website');
            }])
            ->get();
and resulting 'creator' is null

Comment: Can you show where your `Vote` model? How are votes and creator connected? Separate tables with foreign keys? Just edit your question ans insert the needed infos properly formatted.

Comment: Pls look at EDITED

Comment: You need to select the `id` field because that is the field that joins _votes_ with _users/creators_. I updated my answer.